# Dell Latitude E7450: repeating keystrokes issue

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, dell, bios

A brand new Dell Latitude E7450, with a fresh installation of Ubuntu 14.04.2. Sometimes a pressed key repeats until another key is pressed. This is presumably a BIOS bug.

Here's a discussion about it in [Dell's community website](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/software-os/f/3525/p/19618638/20748484).

Since Canonical have [certified this model](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201408-15385/), I have opened a [launchpad question](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu-certification/+question/264500) about it.

Since Dell works closely with Canonical on their products, I was wondering whether Canonical can get a formal reply from Dell about this issue (which apparently affects most if not all Linux distributions).

Comment: I have reported a bug in [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1439850).

Answer (score 1):

This was resolved in the latest bios update A04;  See release notes here:  http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=MWPFJ